# Fetch all orders from a particular orderid

Tags: magento2, orders, collection

I want all orders from a particular orderId.

```
  <?php 
    namespace Racom\Chatbotapi\Model;

    use Racom\Chatbotapi\Api\ChatbotapiInterface;

    class Chatbotapi implements ChatbotapiInterface
    {
        protected $order;

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
        ) {
            $this->order = $order;
        }



        /**
         * Returns the Orders list.
         *
         * @api
         * @param Integer $orderId order Id.
         * @return string Greeting message with users name.
         */
        public function getOrder($orderId) 
        {
            $productCollection = $this->order->load($orderId);

            $a = $productCollection->getItems();

            $v = json_encode($a);

            return $v;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

First we need to create api token an consumer key.

Goto the admin **system->Extensions->Intergration->Add new Intergration.**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require('vendor/zendframework/zend-server/src/Client.php');
require('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client.php');
require('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client/Common.php');

$wsdlurl = 'http://127.0.0.1/magentoee2.5/soap/defaultwsdl&services=salesOrderManagementV1';

$token = 'uruw86n0pywpfcp11yk39cpgxh0dn4rq';

$opts = ['http' => ['header' => "Authorization: Bearer ".$token]];

$opts = ['http' => ['header' => "Authorization: Bearer "]];

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$serviceArgs = array('searchCriteria'=> 
    array('filterGroups' => 
        [ 
            array ('filters' => 
                [
                    array('field' =>'id',
                          'value' => '1' , 
                          'condition_type' => 'eq')
                ]
            )
        ]
    )
);

$soapClient = new \Zend\Soap\Client($wsdlurl);

$soapClient->setSoapVersion(SOAP_1_2);

$soapClient->setStreamContext($context);

$result = $soapClient->salesOrderManagementV1GetStatus(array('id' => 20));

echo "<pre>"; print_r($result);
```

Hope it helps.